# Why is Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly() returning different result inside a NuGet package?

Tags: c#, reflection, nuget, .net-assembly

I'm new to creating NuGet packages and I ran the following code snippet in various environments:

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Tries to find type by name in the executing assembly and after that
/// in referenced assemblies.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="typeName">Name of the type to find (can be full or assembly qualified name as well).</param>
/// <returns>Type found using the given name (or null if not found).</returns>
public static Type FindType(string typeName)
{
    if (typeName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(typeName));

    // Helper method for finding the type in an assembly
    Type Finder(Assembly ass) => ass?.GetTypes().FirstOrDefault(type =>
        typeName.In(type.Name, type.FullName, type.AssemblyQualifiedName)
    );

    // Get the current assembly
    var executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    // Check if the type is inside the current assembly
    var targetType = Finder(executingAssembly);

    // Go through all of the referenced assemblies
    foreach (var assName in executingAssembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
    {
        // If the type was found, return it
        if (targetType != null)
            return targetType;

        // Check if the type is inside the assembly
        targetType = Finder(Assembly.Load(assName));
    }

    return null; // Type wasn't found, return null
}
```

If I run it as local function or through a referenced project, it works fine, but when I create a NuGet package and call the method using the implementation of the method inside the NuGet package, it returns null.

The method `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly` claims it returns `The assembly that contains the code that is currently executing` and yet I get different results when running it from NuGet package.

What can I do to get the correct output from the method if I pack it inside NuGet package?

Comment: try `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not following the advice given in the [remarks of the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Yes, I want it to be a utility method if there is a requirement to fetch a type by name. I use reflection for few things and `Type.FindType(string typeName)` feels like it doesn't cover that many cases.

Comment: @JohanP Thank you! This worked. I've checked what the executing assembly returns. It returns the assembly of the NuGet package project. I don't know if that is intended or not, but it sure is confusing to work with. Is there any way to get the actual executing assembly? Maybe through AppDomain? I didn't find any indicators of what is being executed in that class' members... Also, I've just tried with `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly()` and that one works as I expected - it returns the assembly that calls the method from NuGet package.